# Assets for ExpressionEngine 3.x

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

Will Assets be updated to work with EE 3.x?

We're developing a website for a client that will be load balanced and using S3 for files and would like to use Assets for the S3 integration, however, the site will be using EE 3.1 and assets only suports 2.x currently.

What is the timeframe for a 3.x Assets compatible update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ETA has been announced, more info: https://pixelandtonic.com/blog/ee3-plans.

Or follow/tweet [Pixel & Tonic on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pixelandtonic)